# After using Filter of spring-session-jdbc session object is empty in later CompositeFilter

Tags: spring, jdbc, spring-session

**Problem Describe(seems timing problem):**

> After using SpringSessionRepositoryFilter, session object is empty during 
>   the processing period of OtherFilter at the begining of every request

**What I have tried:**

> - In the Controller and JSP after OtherFilter, session object is not    empty and works fine
> - Without using springSessionRepositoryFilter, session object is    notempty and works fine in OtherFilter

**The configuratioin is like below:**

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.filter.CompositeFilter" name="springChainFilter">
    <property name="filters">
        <list>
            <bean id="springSessionRepositoryFilter" class="org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter">
            </bean>

            <!--Other Later Filter -->
            <bean id="otherFilter" class="xxx.xxx.OtherFilter">
            </bean>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.session.jdbc.config.annotation.web.http.JdbcHttpSessionConfiguration"/>

<bean class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
    <constructor-arg ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>

<bean id="cookieSerializer" class="org.springframework.session.web.http.DefaultCookieSerializer">
    <property name="cookieName" value="JSESSIONID" />
</bean>
```

**OtherFilter Defination is like below:**

```
public class OtherFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {


    @Autowired
    private SessionObj sessionObj;

    ......
}
```

**Session Object Defination is like below:**

```
@Component
@SessionScope
public class SessionObj implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


    private String xxId;

    ......
}
```

**Environment Version Info:**

> - spring-session-jdbc-2.1.5.RELEASE
> - wildfly-11.0.0.Final
> - Oracle Database 18c Express Edition Release 18.0.0.0.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Another Solution for this Question**

> Add the requestContextFilter between springSessionRepositoryFilter and
>   otherFilter

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.filter.CompositeFilter" name="springChainFilter">
    <property name="filters">
        <list>
            <bean id="springSessionRepositoryFilter" class="org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter">
            </bean>
            <!--Request Context Filter -->
            <bean id="requestContextFilter" class="org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter" />
            <!--Other Later Filter -->
            <bean id="otherFilter" class="xxx.xxx.OtherFilter">
            </bean>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

*In RequestContextFilter(applied by spring framework)*

- the wrappedRequest is exposed to the current thread, through both 
  LocaleContextHolder and  RequestContextHolder
- the [requestAttributes] is bound with an instance of
  SessionRepositoryRequestWrapper (do thing like FrameworkSevlet do in
  future)

Answer (score 0):

**The Reason for this Question**

> - @Autowired SessionObj in OtherFilter
> - @Autowired SessionObj in Controller after OtherFilter

Both of the situation above, DI source is the request#getsession() which is bind to [requestAttributes] object.

```
org.springframework.web.context.request.ServletRequestAttributes

    protected final HttpSession getSession(boolean allowCreate) {
        if (isRequestActive()) {
            HttpSession session = this.request.getSession(allowCreate);
            this.session = session;
            return session;
        }
    }
```

There are milestones below during one request:

*sequence from a to e*

> a. In RequestContextListner

- the object [requestAttributes] is binded with an instance of
  HttpServletRequestImpl(without session info from DB)

  org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener

  ```
  public void requestInitialized(ServletRequestEvent requestEvent) {
      if (!(requestEvent.getServletRequest() instanceof HttpServletRequest)) {
          throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                  "Request is not an HttpServletRequest: " + requestEvent.getServletRequest());
      }
      HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) requestEvent.getServletRequest();
      ServletRequestAttributes attributes = new ServletRequestAttributes(request);
      request.setAttribute(REQUEST_ATTRIBUTES_ATTRIBUTE, attributes);
      LocaleContextHolder.setLocale(request.getLocale());
      RequestContextHolder.setRequestAttributes(attributes);
  }
  ```

> b. In SessionRepositoryFilter

- request is wrapped with SessionRepositoryRequestWrapper(with session
  info from DB)
- but, the object [requestAttributes] is not rebinded
  with an instance of SessionRepositoryRequestWrapper

  org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter

  ```
  protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request,
          HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
          throws ServletException, IOException {
      request.setAttribute(SESSION_REPOSITORY_ATTR, this.sessionRepository);

      SessionRepositoryRequestWrapper wrappedRequest = new SessionRepositoryRequestWrapper(
              request, response);
      SessionRepositoryResponseWrapper wrappedResponse = new SessionRepositoryResponseWrapper(
              wrappedRequest, response);

      try {
          filterChain.doFilter(wrappedRequest, wrappedResponse);
      }
  }
  ```

> c. In OtherFilter

- SessionObj is Injected through [requestAttributes] binded with an
  instance of HttpServletRequestImpl(without session info from DB), so
  it is empty

> d. In FrameworkServlet

- the object [requestAttributes] is rebinded with an instance of
  SessionRepositoryRequestWrapper(with session info from DB) which was
  wrapped in the previous b process

  org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet

  ```
  protected final void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
          throws ServletException, IOException {

      ServletRequestAttributes requestAttributes = buildRequestAttributes(request, response, previousAttributes);
      initContextHolders(request, localeContext, requestAttributes);
      }

  private void initContextHolders(HttpServletRequest request,
          @Nullable LocaleContext localeContext, @Nullable RequestAttributes requestAttributes) {

      if (requestAttributes != null) {
          RequestContextHolder.setRequestAttributes(requestAttributes, this.threadContextInheritable);
      }

  }
  ```

> e. In Controller after OtherFilter

- SessionObj is Injected through [requestAttributes] binded with an
  instance of SessionRepositoryRequestWrapper(with session info from
  DB), so it works fine

**One Solution For this Question**

> Add a Session Retrieve Filter between springSessionRepositoryFilter
>   and otherFilter

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.filter.CompositeFilter" name="springChainFilter">
    <property name="filters">
        <list>
            <bean id="springSessionRepositoryFilter" class="org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter">
            </bean>
            <!--Session Retrieve Filter -->
            <bean id="sessionRetrieveFilter" class="xxx.xxx.SessionRetrieveFilter">
            <!--Other Later Filter -->
            <bean id="otherFilter" class="xxx.xxx.OtherFilter">
            </bean>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

> In Session Retrieve Filter bind the [requestAttributes] with an
>   instance of SessionRepositoryRequestWrapper (do thing like
>   FrameworkSevlet do in future)

```
xxx.xxx.SessionRetrieveFilter

    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        RequestAttributes wrappedAttributes = new ServletRequestAttributes(request, response);
        RequestContextHolder.setRequestAttributes(wrappedAttributes);

        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
```